# How can I delete a document which does not have collection name by its id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model which has a nested field like this:

```
 static getSchema (){
        return {
            document_template: {
                type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: TEMPLATE_MODEL_NAME
            },

            department: {
                type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: DEPARTMENT_MODEL_NAME
            },

            fields: {
                type: [ new Mongoose.Schema({
                    key: {
                        type: String,
                        required: true,
                        trim: true
                    },
                    value: {
                        type: Object,
                        required: true,
                    }
                }) ],
                required: false
            }
        };
    } /* getSchema() */
```

As you can see, the "fields" field contains an array of objects. Because I defined a new schema for objects in the array, every objects in that array have an "_id" field. But there is no collection name in the database for these objects. How can I delete these documents which do not have any collection name but have an _id?

Here is an example of a document:

```
{
                "id": "5d232d9ed64d4ea7bdd1cac5",
                "template_id": "5d1df82b9bbf985a5aaac50e",
                "department": "5d1dc4d9c7c4504fef430eec",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "id": "5d29967eb60ca9f88d97451b",
                        "key": "field 3",
                        "value": "333"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5d29967eb60ca9f88d97451a",
                        "key": "field 2",
                        "value": "asde"
                    }
                ]
}
```

I want to delete objects in the fields array by using just their id. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in mongodb to do this.

Sample:

```
YourModel.updateMany({}, {$pull: {fields: {id: your_id}}})
```

Or if you want to delete an array of id:

```
YourModel.updateMany({}, {$pull: {fields: {id: {$in: your_array_id}}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the "fields" array and use `.map()` function to get the array of "id". Once you have array of id, use `.indexOf()` to get the index of passing parameter (id). If id exists, use `.splice()` and afterwards save the model.

```
const index = YOUR_MODEL.fields.map(item => item.id).indexOf(req.params.id);
if(index > -1){
YOUR_MODEL.fields.splice(index, 1);
      await YOUR_MODEL.save();
}else{
 res.status(404).send('Field not found')
}
```

Comment: You should explain why this answer could work, by the way,  What happens when indexOf returns -1?